# Why is it safe to leave Hellions close to creep?

Tags: starcraft-2

In TvZ videos from day9 I saw the following a few times: Terran scouted Zerg base and scouted some spine crawlers. But doesn't try to go inside of the base, instead sitting outside and waiting. He scouts zerglings, banelings and actually doesn't move his hellions away but wait just where the creep ends.

From my perspective, Zerg can easily surround those hellions with some zerlings and kill them. Terran should **constantly** keep an eye on these hellions to pull them back and micro to keep them alive.

I don't think even PRO players constantly watching the mini-map. They need do other stuff and they risk to loose those hellions.

Question: What is a proper way to keep scouts on the front of opponent base and watch them constantly?

Comment: One of the advantages of parking Hellions just outside the Zerg's base is for creep control. The Zerg player would have to find a way to move creep forward (i.e. getting Lair, have an Overlord generate creep below a cliff, and plant an active tumour on the generated creep).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, that is all that they're doing. Basically constantly looking at the hellions.

Nobody really watches them constantly - but you look at them every couple of milliseconds, which is usually enough since zerglings are only slightly faster than hellions on creep.

As for a "proper way" of doing it: Simply learn to watch the minimap constantly. Force yourself to constantly do it, and after a while you will notice moving enemy forces easily. As a bonus, play around with the color options and set it so that you are always blue and your enemy is always red, this will make things easier to spot.

Comment: Also, just keeping a peripheral awareness of the minimap, you can be looking at the main screen, but immediately notice even the smallest red blip on the minimap without even looking directly at it.